# Oracle Apex 5 Installation Issue

Tags: oracle-apex-5

After completing the installation steps I am facing following Message.

Authentication Required

The server http://localhost:8080 requires a username and password. the Server says:XDB.

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUi4h.png)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple after executing the Apex 5 installation scripts you just have to go to following link:

http://localhost:8081/apex/admin